# Duplicating Pandas Dataframe rows based on string split, without iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a multiindex, where one of thecolumns represents multiple values, separated by a "|", like this:

```
            value
left right 
x    a|b    2
y    b|c|d  -1
```

I want to duplicate the rows based on the "right" column, to get something like this:

```
           values
left right
x    a     2
x    b     2
y    b     -1
y    c     -1
y    d     -1
```

The solution I have to this feels wrong and runs slow, because it's based on iteration:

```
df2 = df.iloc[:0]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    stgs = index[1].split("|")
    for s in stgs:
        row.name = (index[0], s)
        df2 = df2.append(row)
```

Is there a more vectored way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas Series have a dedicated method `split` to perform this operation

split works only on Series so isolate the Column you want

```
SO = df['right']
```

Now 3 steps at once: `spilt` return A Series of array. `apply(pd.Series, 1)` convert array in columns. `stack` stacks you columns into a unique column

```
S1 = SO.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
```

The only issue is that you have now a multi-index. So just drop the level you don`t need

```
S1.index.droplevel(-1)
```

**Full example**

```
SO = pd.Series(data=["a,b", "b,c,d"])

S1 = SO.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
S1
Out[4]:
0  0    a
   1    b
1  0    b
   1    c
   2    d

S1.index = S1.index.droplevel(-1) 
S1 
Out[5]:
0    a
0    b
1    b
1    c
1    d
```

Comment: This is nice, but how about keeping the `right` column?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I have a similar problem with survey results and mult-answer questions... like "Which of the following phones have you owned? (a) Galaxy S10 (b) Pixel 3 (c) Huwaei P30" ending up with data like "userid2,'Pixel 3, Huwaei P30'"

Answer (score 2):

Building upon the answer @xNoK, I am adding here the additional step needed to include the result back in the original DataFrame.

We have this data:

```
arrays = [['x', 'y'], ['a|b', 'b|c|d']]
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['left', 'right'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=midx, data=[2, -1], columns=['value'])
df

Out[17]:
            value
left right
x    a|b        2
y    b|c|d     -1
```

First, let's generate the values for `right` index as @xNoK suggested. First take the Index level we want to work on by `index.levels[1]` and convert it it to series so that we can perform the `str.split()` function, and finally `stack()` it to get the result we want.

```
new_multi_idx_val = df.index.levels[1].to_series().str.split('|').apply(pd.Series).stack()
new_multi_idx_val

Out[18]:
right
a|b    0    a
       1    b
b|c|d  0    b
       1    c
       2    d
dtype: object
```

Now we want to put this value in the original DataFrame `df`. To do that, let's change its shape so that result we generated in the previous step could be copied.

In order to do that, we can repeat the rows (including the indexes) by a number of `|` present in `right` level of multi-index. `df.index.levels[1].to_series().str.split('|').apply(lambda x: len(x))` gives the number of times a row (including index) should be repeated. We apply this to the function `index.repeat()` and fetch values at those indexes to create a new DataFrame `df_repeted`.

```
df_repeted = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.index.levels[1].to_series().str.split('|').apply(lambda x: len(x)))]
df_repeted

Out[19]:
            value
left right
x    a|b        2
     a|b        2
y    b|c|d     -1
     b|c|d     -1
     b|c|d     -1
```

Now `df_repeted` DataFrame is in a shape where we could change the index to get the answer we want.

Replace the index of `df_repeted` with desired values as following:

```
df_repeted.index = [df_repeted.index.droplevel(1), new_multi_idx_val]
df_repeted.index.rename(names=['left', 'right'], inplace=True)
df_repeted

Out[20]:
            value
left right
x    a          2
     b          2
y    b         -1
     c         -1
     d         -1
```